# How can I disable scroll switching in gnome taskbar under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, taskbar, scrolling

When you put your mouse cursor on the task bar or desktop switcher and roll the scroll wheel it switches between applications or desktops (sorta like when you alt-tab). This is all well and good however I find it to be very irritating because it always happens on accident (I am on a laptop with a touchpad). How does one go about disabling this feature?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written by linunix @ https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/ha2w1r/how_do_i_disable_switching_between_windows_when/fv0cb6c/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3,

If you're indeed using Dash-to-Panel (version 40 here) under GNOME, right-click on the Show-App icon ([image]) of the task bar and open "Dash-to-Panel settings", then go to Action tab and change the setting from "**Scroll icon action**" from "**Cycle window**" to "**Do nothing**".

[image]

Had to struggle with that one a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

By default, (on Ubuntu 18.04) viewport switching is bound to a horizontal two-finger swipe. The sensitivity is very high, so when you scroll vertically you also easily scroll horizontally accidentally.

Disabling horizontal scroll was also more of a hassle than I expected (e.g. `dconf-editor` and `ccsm` didn't do the job). `libinput-tools` did it for me though, see further instructions:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1130184/1034363

Answer (score -1):

best answer I can find. I wish this was just a setting in gnome though:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-panel/+bug/39328

Comment: That's a very lenghty discussion, and contains only touching information